# regex - disallowing a sequence of characters

Tags: java, regex

I have a variable in the form of {varName} or {varName, "defaultValue"} and I want a regex that will match it. varName is only alphanumeric and "_" (\w+), and the default value can be anything except the combination of "} which signifies the end of the variable. White space doesn't matter between the braces, comma, varName or defaultValue. So far the regex that I have come up with is

```
\{\s*(\w+)\s*(,\s*\"([^(\"\})]*)\"\s*)?\}
```

The problem is that the match ends at the first " OR } and not the combination, i.e. {hello, "world"} does match but {hello, "wor"ld"} or {hello, "wor}ld"}

Any idea how to solve this? In case this helps, I'm coding it using Java.

Comment: 2 questions: `1. `Is your default value always wrapped in double quotes `"`? `2. ` How come you have `"wor"ld"` as a default value, it should be `"wor\"ld"`.

Comment: 1. Yes the default value is always wrapped in double quotes. 2.In the content itself (a text file) it will appear as "worl"d". I have found the solution and posted it as one of the answers. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution to my own question, it's only fair to share. The following regex:

```
\{\s*(\w+)\s*(,\s*\"((.*?)\s*\")?\})
```

Will do the trick, stopping at the first sequence of '"}'

In Java, this will be (continuing previous answer's example):

```
final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\{\\s*(\\w+)\\s*(,\\s*\"(.*?)\\s*\"\\s*)?\\}");
Matcher m1 = p.matcher("{hello, \"world\"}");
if (m1.matches()) {
    System.out.println("var1:" + m1.group(1));
    System.out.println("val1:" + m1.group(3));
}
Matcher m2 = p.matcher("{hello, \"wor\"rld\"}\"}");
if (m2.matches()) {
    System.out.println("var2:" + m2.group(1));
System.out.println("val2:" + m2.group(3));
}

/* Output
var1:hello
val1:world
var2:hello
val2:wor"rld"}
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

```
final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\{\\s*(\\w+)\\s*(,\\s*\"((?!\"\\}).*)\"\\s*)?\\}");
Matcher m1 = p.matcher("{hello, \"world\"}");
if (m1.matches()) {
    System.out.println("var1:" + m1.group(1));
    System.out.println("val1:" + m1.group(3));
}
Matcher m2 = p.matcher("{hello, \"wor}ld\"}");
if (m2.matches()) {
    System.out.println("var2:" + m2.group(1));
    System.out.println("val2:" + m2.group(3));
}
Matcher m3 = p.matcher("{hello, \"wor}\"ld\"}");
if (m3.matches()) {
    System.out.println("var3:" + m3.group(1));
    System.out.println("val3:" + m3.group(3));
}

/*output: 
var1:hello
val1:world
var2:hello
val2:wor}ld
var3:hello
val3:wor}"ld */
```

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear in my question, but the content itself is more than one variable. In case of '{hello, "world"} "}' I need just 'hello' and 'world' but I get 'hello' and 'world"}'. The variable value should stop at the first "}.

Comment: Maybe this is too much to be asked for a single regex. Try using StringUtils.substringBefore(m1.group(3), "\"}")

Comment: We are talking about a huge string where performance is crucial, and I don't know how many stray "} I will have in the content :)